# How to pass variable number of functions as parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and i'm trying to refactor some code in Kotlin.

I have this piece of code that im calling in multiple places which i'd like to call a single function instead

```
Mockito.`when`(mockedSkillMaxCountRepository.getSkillMaxCount()).thenReturn(
     SkillMaxCount(count = 65),
     SkillMaxCount(count = 65)
)
```

And I want to do something like this where the number of parameters can be any number

```
mockSkillMaxCount(SkillMaxCount(count = 65), SkillMaxCount(count = 65),...)

private fun mockSkillMaxCount(SkillMaxCount(count = 65),SkillMaxCount(count = 65),...){       
     Mockito.`when`(mockedSkillMaxCountRepository.getSkillMaxCount()).thenReturn(params)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vararg](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) modifier:

```
private fun mockSkillMaxCount(vararg skills: SkillMaxCount) {
    Mockito.`when`(mockedSkillMaxCountRepository.getSkillMaxCount()).thenReturn(*skills)
}
```